# Accidental mark for delete - entire depot and reverting - perforce

Tags: perforce

I accidently marked for delete my depo which has thousands of files. but when I try to revert my p4v client hangs and stops working.

I have everything setup on my windows xp virtual machine.

I am trying to use the comand line as follows. (my workspace is 1 to 1 mapped with depo.

Initially i tried other revart varients mentiond on the perforce website : `p4 [g-opts] revert [ -a -n -k -c changelist# ]` but to no avail.

`p4v -c workspace revert -c default //..` and the process has been running for two hours now.

Anyone- any idea on how to revert the mark for deleted files

Comment: That would be the right command. However, if you find it too painful, you might want to do it in chunks. On a long-ago workstation, I found the workstation to be so under-powered I could not handle >10,000 files at a time, yet splitting into chunks worked just fine. After I got a new workstation (twice the RAM), I had no trouble handing more than 30,000 files at a time (all against the same Perforce server).

Comment: Your command example has you running "p4v" instead of "p4" -- is that a typo or is that what you tried to run?

Comment: Did you mean to type `//..` or `//...`?